# Dask Jobqueue - Why does using processes result in cancelled jobs?

Tags: python, dask, slurm, dask-distributed, dask-jobqueue

#### Main issue

I'm using Dask Jobequeue on a Slurm supercomputer. My workload includes a mix of threaded (i.e. numpy) and python workloads, so I think a balance of threads and processes would be best for my deployment (which is the default behaviour). However, in order for my jobs to run I need to use this basic configuration:

```
cluster = SLURMCluster(cores=20,
                    processes=1,
                    memory="60GB",
                    walltime='12:00:00',
                    ...
                    )
cluster.adapt(minimum=0, maximum=20)
client = Client(cluster)
```

which is entirely threaded. The tasks also seem to take longer than I would naively expect (a large part of this is a lot of file reading/writing). Switching to purely processes, i.e.

```
cluster = SLURMCluster(cores=20,
                    processes=20,
                    memory="60GB",
                    walltime='12:00:00',
                    ...
                    )
```

results in slurm jobs which are immediately killed by Slurm as they are launched, with the only output like:

```
slurmstepd: error: *** JOB 11116133 ON nid00201 CANCELLED AT 2021-04-29T17:23:25 ***
```

Choosing a balanced configuration (i.e. default)

```
cluster = SLURMCluster(cores=20,
                    memory="60GB",
                    walltime='12:00:00',
                    ...
                    )
```

results in a strange intermediate behaviour. The task will run near to completion (i.e. 900/1000  work tasks) then a number of the workers will be killed, and the progress will drop back down to, say, 400/1000 tasks.

Any thoughts on what's going on here?

#### Some extra context

On this particular machine, I've been advised by the sysadmins that for multicore (non MPI, e.g. python multiprocessing) the jobs should be launched using

```
srun -n 1 -c 20 python ...
```

Otherwise the processes will run on a single core. So in my cluster config I have

```
cluster = SLURMCluster(
    ...
    python='srun -n 1 -c 20 python',
    ...
)
```

My guess is that the difference between using dask threads/processes should affect this, as we still want all 20 cores assigned to job.

Additionally, I need to load a module which makes a number of compiled tools available, but unfortunately also changes the `PYTHONPATH`. My (not at all ideal) workaround for this is:

```
cluster = SLURMCluster(
    ...
    env_extra=[
        'module load mymodule',
        'unset PYTHONPATH',
        'source /home/$(whoami)/.bashrc',
        'conda activate mycondaenv'
    ],
    ...
)
```

This seems to successfully ensure that the `python` called above is the same `mycondaenv` environment that I use to launch the dask jobs.

EDIT:

#### Updates

Following @SultanOrazbayev's suggestion, I looked that the Slurm job info for the failed job ids. They all result in:

```
slurm_load_jobs error: Invalid job id specified
```

Further, I've found that using `cluster.scale` rather than `cluster.adapt` results in a successful run of the work. Perhaps the issue here is how `adapt` is trying to scale the number of jobs?

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason is that the jobs are cancelled due to incompatible resource requests. The easiest way to resolve this is to inspect `print(cluster.job_script())` and show it to your sysadmin.

Alternatively, check the error logs on the cluster. Running `scontrol show jobid 1234` (where 1234 is the job id) should point you to the reasons for cancellation and relevant logs.

Comment: Thanks. I was already looking at the job script, and they looked completely fine. I had an earlier issue where I was accidentally requesting too many jobs, and that resulted in a visible error in the queue.

The `scrontrol` command is showing that the IDs of the failed jobs aren't valid (I guess they aren't registered by the system?). See updates above

Comment: Given the additional details, your problem might be caused by some of the options you omitted in the question. For example the location of stdout/stderr files.

Comment: I'm not so sure. I just have `log_directory='logs'`, and the files are writing just fine. I think it has more to do with the behaviour of `adapt` vs `scale` (see the update above)